# CodeLite autocomplete cannot find c++ headers

Tags: c++, autocomplete, codelite

CodeLite 7.0, Windows 7, MinGW installed, autocomplete cannot find anything c++ related. I have a workspace and a project in it (just started with CodeLite).

When I try to include a c++ header (e.g. string or vector) or use those classes in my code i get no autocomplete. Compiling and running works fine, just the autocomplete does not.

Under `CodeLite`->`Settings`->`Code Completion`->`CTags` there is a list of MinGW's include folders for c++ (I checked, all headers are in those folders).

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you go to :
`CodeLite -> Workspace -> Retag Workspace (full)` , does it change anything?

And just to make sure: you do have a workspace and project, right?

Eran

Comment: Nothing changed. I noticed now that under "Code Completion" options, under advanced field, there is a list of file types set to *.cpp;*.cc;*.cxx;*.h;*.hpp;*.c;*.c++;*.tcc;*.hxx;*.h++; Perhaps CodeLite cannot find c++ files that have no extension (e.g. "string" header file)?

Comment: Not really. CodeLite follows the `#include` statements in your codelite. So even if you include a `.txt` file, it will be scanned and parsed. Beside, it works for me ;)

Comment: I will try creating a new workspace/project. I guessed it should work out of the box, perhaps something went wrong on workspace/project creation.

Answer (score 1):

I may be way off base here, but found a similar (same?) issue.

This does NOT work:

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

vec (No autocomplete)
```

However, both other ways work as expected:

```
#include <vector>

std::vec (Yes autocomplete)
```

OR:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vec (Yes autocomplete)
```

Comment: That was the problem with for me as well. It has been 2 years, isn't this a bug?